# Take all available viewport height via CSS

Tags: css, html, height, viewport

[image: Illustration]

Is there is a way to force div to take all available height **not knowing** heights of elements above?

If height is known, than vh units can be used, for example if #header's height is 30px, I can apply `height: 100vh - 30px;` to #view.

I made small example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5eoe6xLp/6/):

```
<div id="header">
    Header
</div>
<div id="view">
    View
</div>

#header {
    height: 50px;
}
#view {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome, but I want to have cross browser support.

Comment: Sorry, initially I forgot to wrap expression with calc() function and remove margins. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to relate to other element height or own top property?

Answer (score 9):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5eoe6xLp/1/)

Try [CSS calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```
#view {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
}
```

Comment: Yep, I agree with this.  Just clean up your margins to stop the scrolling.  http://jsfiddle.net/5eoe6xLp/2/

Comment: No, I just forgot to add calc func, but the goal was to do that not knowing about 50px. And, maybe, support header dynamical height.

Comment: So what about using javascript for that or jquery give it a try!

Comment: I know that this can be done in coded way, but this is definitely markup task, so I'm trying to find a way to use pure CSS here.